# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 404 in react

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Api = () => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`);
            console.log(res.data.name);
        }
        getData();
    })
    return (
        <>
            <h1>You Choose {num} value</h1>
            <select value={num} onChange={(event) => {
                setNum(event.target.value)
            }}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
        </>
    )
}


export default Api;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API returned 404 because **num** is undefined. When executed, the code will call `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/undefined`

Things you can do to fix it :

- Give an initial value to num : `const [num, setNum] = useState(1);`
- Catch the error when you call the API.
- And not related with your question, but you have to put a second parameter to the function `useEffect` : when this second parameter changes, the first parameter is executed.

Have a look at this sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-pascal-vxq65